# Failed to resolve: com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1 how to fix this

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I try to build android pdf reader and add a library **com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2** then it shows the following error

My **build.gradle** file is please guys help me to fix the problem and I want to build the app as much

please guys help me

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dash.songuploader"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildToolsVersion '32.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0'
//    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    //pdf library
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    //dbshbs
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
//    implementation 'com.joanzapata.pdfview:android-pdfview:2.8.2@aar'
}
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have Offline mode on.

Answer (score 10):

Many of the comments above talk about adding jcenter() to settings.gradle.

That did not work for me. In order to get my Flutter project running again, I had to add jcenter() to the **android/build.gradle** file.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add jcenter()  to settings.gradle

Comment: For those unfamiliar with settings.gradle (like me) where would this go in that file?

Comment: The settings.file is in Android project in the root folder

Answer (score 4):

```
implementation 'com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
```

In android studio, I just replace jcenter() with mavenCentral() and replace dependency with this.

Answer (score 1):

[image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfTDs.png)

```
    dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Add jcenter() to settings.gradle

Answer (score 1):

for flutter project, that use flutter_pdfview package.
try add jcenter() on top of maven repo to build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In android Studio, adding jcenter() at following location in gradle.setting helped me in android studio

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for this version `2.8.2` its just available on jCenter, but if you have issues with jCenter, you can use alternative, like jitpack

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

implementation 'com.github.barteksc:AndroidPdfViewer:master-SNAPSHOT'
```

Answer (score 0):

add `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }`
to settings.gradle(Project Settings).

like this:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

}